# Web spider based on scrapy breaks down after being packed by Pyinstaller

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, pyqt4, pyinstaller

based on scrapy, I construct a python web spider.A Windows GUI based on PyQt4 is combined with this web spider.There are some details:

- OS: Windows7 x64
- Python: 2.7.6
- IDE: PyCharm
- GUI: PyQt4
- spider: scrapy
- package tool: Pyinstaller

All is well when i run it under PyCharm, and i get everything i except.Then, i packet this project in a standalone *.exe file,i got some errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
File "scholar\SpiderProcess.py", line 81, in run
File "site-packages\scrapy\utils\project.py", line 61, in get_project_settings
File "site-packages\scrapy\settings\__init__.py", line 109, in setmodule
File "importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
ImportError: No module named settings
```

Here is my project file tree:

```
ScholarSpider
|____scrapy.cfg
|____main.py
|____installer.py
|____scholar
     |______init__.py
     |____items.py
     |____pipelines.py
     |____settings.py
     |____SpiderProcess.py
     |____spider
          |_______init__.py
          |____PLOS_Spider.py
          |____ASM_Spider.py
```

***main.py*** is the entry

***installer.py*** is the Pyinstaller file

```
# installer.py
import os
if __name__=='__main__':
    from PyInstaller.__main__ import run
    opts=['-c','-F','main.py',
          '-p', r'D:\Program Files\Python 2.7.6\Lib\site-packages\scrapy;'
                r'D:\Program Files\Python 2.7.6\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils']
    run(opts)
```

spider is running in a standalone process created by multiprocess.Process(implimented in ***SpiderProcess.py***).It starts when i click the button in the GUI.Every time a click the button, it breaks down and send the error message.What's wonders me is that the **settings.py** module is exists in my project and everything is OK in PyCharm.

Can anybody tells me what's wrong?

THANK YOU!